# Why does Script Compiling take so long?

Tags: javascript, html, performance

Here is a snapshot of by page load times from the performance window in chrome. As you can see, most of the load time is Evaluate and Compile script. Is there any way to Precompile script to make it load faster?
What actually is happening during Parse Html, and Compile and Evaluate Script?
[image]

Comment: "*What actually is happening during Parse Html, and Compile and Evaluate Script?*" - just what the names say.

Comment: "*Is there any way to Precompile script to make it load faster?*" - no. (Some browsers do internally cache the compiled script so that they have to compile it only on first load). The solution is to make your script smaller and have it do less things.